# How to write inline CSS to web2py view

Tags: css, layout, inline, web2py

My web2py project has an html file that contains only these two lines of code

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=form}}
```

I want to write some inline css that should override the css that will be loaded from *layout.html*. I want to know if this is possible and if so, then how?

Here's the style that I want to add

```
.error {
    margin-top: 0px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can add inline CSS:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=form}}
<style>
.error {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
```